# How to solve this problem? TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'prevDeps.length')

Tags: reactjs

The main problem is that I use VSC and I use commend: cmd + shift + f, to search across all my files and folders, and do not find any variable named `prevDeps.length`
I guess it could be connected with firebase/auth because I read this https://blog.logrocket.com/user-authentication-firebase-react-apps/
tutorial and then the following error occur.

I find something on stack overflow, but the guy had problem with react-native, and have problem with nextjs.

Comment: prevDeps is undefined, `console.log(prevDeps)` for to check.

Comment: @sushildlh OP says there is no `prevDeps` in the code

Comment: I get an error when I use this commend, but in console I find more information about this variable, it is from react-dom-development.js and I many more places.

Comment: You likely have a library or other third party code in use and you are not initializing it correctly with the data it expects. You should go over all usages of your libraries and initialization code and compare to their respective documentation sites.